# Nested subscriptions with Conditional Logic

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have a CRUD angular 5.5 component that uses the routing parameters to set it self up in various modes(new, edit, view). Nested subscription should be avoided but I am not sure how to do that since I need some basic conditional logic.

```
    this.route.params.subscribe((params) => {
       this.action  = params.action;
       if (this.action  === 'new') {
           // get the formation need to make a new item
           this.service.getList().subscribe((data) = > this.list = data);
           // do stuff
       } else { 
           // view or edit a item
           this.service.getItem(params.id).subscribe((data) = > this.item = data);
           // do other stuff
       }
    });
```

I tried using switch map but I am not sure if really that much better because now I am returning a complex type of `observable<item>  | observable<item[]>`. There has to be a better more expressive way to do this.

```
this.route.paramMap.switchMap((params: ParaMap) => {
   this.action = params.get('action');
   if (this.action === 'new) {
     return this.service.getList();
   } else {
     return this.service.getItem(params.get('id));
   }
}).subscribe((data) => {
  if (this.action === 'new) {
     this.list = data;
     // do stuff
  } else {
     this.item = data;
     // do other stuff
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A much better way to solve this would be to change your routing configuration. For CRUD app, something like this will work:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', component: IndexComponent },
  { path: 'create', component: CreateComponent },
  { path: ':id', children: [
      { path: '', component: ShowComponent },
      { path: 'update', component: UpdateComponent },
      { path: 'destroy', component: DestroyComponent },
    ] 
  }
];
```

This way, each component can call the appropriate method on your API service, without the overhead of conditional logic.

Comment: That does line up much better with SOLID principles.